# Shouldn't we use exception handling when we use TestNG in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, exception, testng

I am working on selenium keyword driven framework. I am using exception handling for the methods that the keywords invoke. The following is one of the methods I am using.

```
public void adminvehicletitle(WebElement vehicletitle, String title) {
        LogUtilities.info("------------ Entering vehicle title on admin post vehicle page --------");
        try {
            vehicletitle.sendKeys(title);
            LogUtilities.info("------------ Vehicle title Entered successfully on admin post vehicle page --------");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            LogUtilities.error("------------ "+e+" --------");
        }
    }
```

Now I made the vehicle title display as none so it is not visible. When I run the test with TestNG, it is passing now even though in the logs it is showing the error. In the reports also it is showing that all the test cases are passed.

So my question now is, shouldn't we use exception handling with TestNG? Can someone answer this please?

Thank you.

Comment: When you "handle" an exception, technically there is no error.  If you want your test to fail, you need to also use Assert so that it gets flagged as a failure.

Comment: There is nothing in your try block indicating to TestNG that you consider this test passed.  There is nothing your catch block indicating to TestNG that you consider this test failed.  You need to assert Something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But again even if we don't use exceptions, in TestNG in the report generated, it will still show the exception generated. When we want to make the test failed, do we have to use exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In test development, swallowing exception is a wrong practice. You have to throw back in the test. If a test throws expection, then it is a failer case in usual postive case. So it has to be marked as failure. If you try catch, the testng will not mark it as failure.

As Selenium methods throw RunTimeException, it will not required explicitly throw here in your case.

If you are interested to log the excpetion for failure case, use testng listner to log based on the test result.

Refer [this blog](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/logging-with-testng-using-listeners) for an example.

If you are willing to log, when there is expection

Comment: Thank you Navarasu, So as per my understanding, if we don't use TestNG, we have to use the exception handling mechanism as we don't want all the test cases stop executing. But we have to explicitly make the test as failed and we can get the reason in the logs, if we capture them. If we use TestNG, we don't have to use exception handling as we can use listeners and also as the report itself shows what the exception is. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you Navarasu. It's very helpful for me.